# Adding usercontrol dynamically through XAML

Tags: .net, wpf, button, user-controls

I have 5 `UserControls` in my project. On `Button` click of the main window, I have to load the respective user control to main window. Is it possible to achieve through XAML?
I am working with MVVM framework.

Comment: Could you explain why using XAML a requirement is? That might help us helping you.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd Just like that i asked. I know if everything is done through xaml binding, code maintainability will be easy.

Comment: What MVVM framework are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Well you could do the following {ulternative to Kazuo's suggestion}... worked fine during my quick test.

```
<Windows.Resources>
    <ComboBox x:Key="options">
        <ControlTemplate x:Name="Button" TargetType="Control">
            <Button/>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate x:Name="ComboBox" TargetType="Control">
            <ComboBox/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
</Windows.Resources>
```

Then in your window item you put something like this

```
<Control x:Name="myCotrol" Margin="364,70,27,215" Template="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource options},Path=SelectedItem}"  />
<TextBox x:Name="Test" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="398,83,-1,0"  Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource options},Path=SelectedIndex}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

with Test being Whatever item decides which control to use.  you can test by putting either 0 or 1 in the Text field of text when you run.  This will then switch between Button or combobox.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You could have the user controls already on the main window in Xaml and have them collapsed. You would have a bool value in your viewmodel that you would bind to the visibility of your user controls via a converter (e.g. true converts to Visibility.Visible). When the button on your main window is clicked you would set your bool value to true and the controls would appear.

Not exactly a pure xaml approach so this may not help you